# How true to the comics is Mysterio's portrayal in "Spider-Man: Far From Home"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, spider-man-far-from-home, mysterio

I have a lot of nostalgia around Mysterio based on old Spider-Man games that I used to play, and have always had the impression of him as one of Spider-Man's oldest and most challenging enemies, but I don't really know anything else about him.

How true to the comics is his portrayal in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, with regards to his origin story, the technological (as opposed to magical) underpinnings of his illusions, etc.?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a pretty decently close adaptation.

1. The name is correct. [Quentin Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterio) indeed goes by the name of Mysterio
2. The purple-green outfit with the fishbowl helmet is Mysterio's archetypical outfit
3. The lack of magic is also correct. Quentin Beck used a combination of psychology and practical effects to trick Spider-Man

However, there are differences.

1. The Quentin Beck of the comics was a special-effects person on movies driven to villain by his failed career as an actor, not an inventor at Starktech
2. Quentin Beck wasn't nearly as attractive as Jake Gyllenhall
3. The comic book Mysterio did not have a team of people helping him (although he was a frequent member of the Sinister Six), but rather generally came up with all of his tricks on his own.

Comment: Comics-Beck also didn't have a support team, but when you think about it, that makes sense and is more realistic. Each of them were specialists, so it doesn't depend on Beck being a Tony Stark level multidisciplinary genius.

Comment: lol +1 for the 2nd difference

Comment: "The comic book Mysterio was a villain from the start, rather than masquerading as a hero" Not exactly. Mysterio was definitely a villain, but in his first fight with Spider-Man in Amazing Spider-Man 13 his MO was to pretend to be a hero while robbing a museum and framing Spider-Man for it.

Comment: Whilst your first difference is correct, it is worth noting that the motivations (overlooked, no credit, etc.) are very similar.

Comment: Additionally it doesn't feel like an arbitrary change - they needed a way to explain the tech Beck had access to, and being a special effects person doesn't really cut it in the MCU age of invisible flying drones. It feels like they were as sympathetic to the comic character as possible while making sensible changes where necessary for the sake of the story.

Comment: @delinear It goes beyond that. It underscores the way Tony Stark treated certain people he cared about, and the effect he had on them (Peter Parker was heavily inspired), versus .... others.

Comment: +1 for not as attractive as Jake Gyllenhall